# seaching app online to play avi got error

Tags: vlc, avi

Can anyone help me?

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.UnicodeDecodeError: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/core.py", line 1086, in _install_mime_types
    details, score)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/core.py", line 363, in add_confirm_package

score, _is_package_restricted(pkg))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/core.py", line 348, in add_confirm

desc = utils.get_package_desc(name, summary)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/utils.py", line 77, in get_package_desc

 markup += "\n%s" % app_comment

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You want to just watch a avi video ?

Comment: ya bro .... i been install Ubuntu Restricted Extras and vlc player also can play it

Comment: okay, so use VLC?

Comment: This question would benefit from expansion and clarification: Exactly what is producing the messages you're showing us, and what else (if anything) have you tried?

Comment: ya bro ... tat was messenge pop when i clicking search app online to play file ... cos my population low dint enough to post picture or video ... sorry

Comment: @KenSeng I don't know if you still want to add an image to your question, but if so, you can post it externally (for example, on http://postimage.org or http://imgur.com), add a link to it in your question, and we can edit your question to add it inline. (It looks like this is solved though, and that it turned out that the information you provided was actually sufficient to point to [the solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/516330/22949).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this command to a terminal to install both programs

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras vlc
```